# When updating SPFx Web Parts, will the pages that already use them update or break?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

In SharePoint Online we have 350 pages that use a custom SPFx Web Part.

Let's say we need to change it. Can I create a new version of it? Will the changes get reflected through all pages? Can this change break all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jose,

Provided that you don't break the compatibility from one version to another, your web parts will update on a site collection by Sir collection basis with very little effort.

When you update your web parts, you should change the package solution number -- I recommend following the [semantic versioning guidelines] (https://semver.org/).

When you upload the new solution and check it in to your app catalog, you'll find that your web parts won't update anywhere, but if you go to each site collection's installed apps, you'll see that it says that a new version is available. You can upgrade from there.

Doing it this way ultimately allows you to control where in your tenant the web part gets updated.

I hope this helps?

Comment: it certainly did! thank

Comment: Hey Hugo..Nice to find you here :)